# How to hold a `Box<dyn MyTrait>` when `MyTrait` has parametrized types?

Tags: rust

I need to hold an option for a runtime-chosen `Box<Device>`:

```
device: Option<Box<dyn Device<'a>>>
```

but the `Device` trait has associated types:

```
pub trait Device<'a> {
    type RxToken: RxToken + 'a;
    type TxToken: TxToken + 'a;
```

I'm getting

> the value of the associated types `RxToken` (from trait
> `virtual_tun::smoltcp::phy::Device`), `TxToken` (from trait
> `virtual_tun::smoltcp::phy::Device`) must be specified

Why do I need to specify these types if they're in a box? Whatever object that implements `Device` that I store in this `Box` is already gonna have its `RxToken` and `TxToken` chosen. I see no reason to have to specify it.

What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not so much the `Box` but the `dyn` that allows you to have dynamic types instead of static (just that `Box` is something that can hold an unsized type).

With that out of the way, you need to specify the associated type because, even though the type of `dyn Device<'_>` is dynamic, you still need to interact with it in a static way. You get into trouble if the trait accepts or returns an associated type (as is the norm).

Extrapolating your example:

```
trait RxToken {}
trait TxToken {}

trait Device<'a> {
    type RxToken: RxToken + 'a;
    type TxToken: TxToken + 'a;
    
    fn read(&self) -> Self::RxToken;
    fn write(&self) -> Self::TxToken;
}

fn main() {
    let device: Option<Box<dyn Device<'_>>> = None;
    
    let _rx_token = device.as_ref().unwrap().read();  // ?
    let _tx_token = device.as_ref().unwrap().write(); // ?
}
```

What would be the type of `_rx_token`? Its not specified anywhere. It can't be `RxToken + 'a` because that is a *bound*, not a *type*. And it can't be `dyn RxToken + 'a` because [unsized rvalues](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48055) are not yet supported.

If you need to use a `dyn Device<'_>` in a completely dynamic way, you can't have associated types. If you still want to have some `RxToken` and `TxToken` be dynamic, you'd need more dynamicism, like:

```
trait Device<'a> {
    fn read(&self) -> Box<dyn RxToken>;
    fn write(&self) -> Box<dyn TxToken>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I need to specify these types if they're in a box? Whatever object that implements Device that I store in this Box is already gonna have its RxToken and TxToken chosen. I see no reason to have to specify it.

Because currently object safety [requires explicitly provided concrete associated types](https://boats.gitlab.io/blog/post/async-methods-ii/).

[There was a pre-rfc to improve that](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-object-safe-traits-with-associated-types/7996) but it apparently went nowhere.

> What can I do in this case?

Either specify those types or do something else.

Comment: The types are different for each `Device` chosen. So there's nothing I can do?

Comment: Don't think so. If the set of all devices is known, maybe you could use an enum instead? Not sure how much it'd help. Alternatively, maybe you could specify trait objects for the tokens or something? Not sure it'd work.